# Rails 4 Devise reactivate "soft deleted" accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Followed this [tutorial on how to do a soft-delete](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account), which works. But if a user decides they want to go back and reactivate the account, what would be the best way to do so? Or is there a wiki for this as well? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the tutorial link you posted, they used time (deleted_at) to determine if a user is deleted (soft-delete).

You can now have a separate route and method for re-activating a user if the login credentials are correct i call mine **reactivate_user**

```
# app/models/user.rb  

  # instead of deleting, indicate the user requested a delete & timestamp it  
  def soft_delete  
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)  
  end  

  def reactivate_user  
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, nil)  
  end 
  # ensure user account is active  
  def active_for_authentication?  
    super && !deleted_at  
  end  

  # provide a custom message for a deleted account   
  def inactive_message   
    !deleted_at ? super : :deleted_account  
  end
```

Comment: It should be `nil` rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Could anyone expand upon this answer? How would you utilize the reactivate_user method when the user tries to sign in, for example? I'm not quite sure how that works.

Comment: This is a bit late but might still be helpful. This depends on the flow(authentication method) you adopt, for example, using ony email and password on a page called reactivate, you take their user email and password, get the user that matches this, you'll prob do something like 

```user = User.find_by(email: params[:email], password: encrypted_password)```
```if user
   user.reactivate_user
end```