# How to allow a user to re-register after Devise soft delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, soft-delete

A junior question here: How do I set up a separate route within sign-up such that if the email exists but has a deleted_at stamp, it can be re-activated?

I'm using Devise with a Ruby on Rails app, and I wanted to have a soft-delete for users. If they changed their minds and came back to the site, I want them to be able to get their info back.

The instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Soft-delete-a-user-when-user-deletes-account) worked great to delete the account. My registration.rb file now includes:

```
  def soft_delete
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
  end

  ensure user account is active
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && !deleted_at
  end

  def inactive_message
    !deleted_at ? super : :deleted_account
  end
```

I created a custom registrations controller, including:

```
class Registrations::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def destroy
    resource.soft_delete
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I try to then reactivate it, the log-in function behaves as though the email doesn't exist (doesn't log in), and the sign-up function behaves as though the email does exist (says, "has already been taken").

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981626/rails-4-devise-reactivate-soft-deleted-accounts) mentions creating a custom method (I did):

```
 def reactivate_user
    update_attribute(:deleted_at, nil)
    registration_session_path
  end
```

but also creating a separate route. I'm not sure how or where to do that with Devise.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Although this is technically possible, you should first make sure, if this is possible from a legal standpoint. As a user I would expect that my data gets deleted when I delete my account. This depends on local law, of course.

Comment: did you see this gem https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia ? or you can update the email to the softdeleted user to `email = "#{ email }_#{ id }"`

Comment: @mbuechmann interesting and glad you brought that up. I'll do some googling.

Comment: hi @KC2018, i am facing a similar issue, what was the solution you implemented?